# Cant open android sdk from terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, android

I am trying yo open the sdk manager.
I downloaded the android sdk command line tools from the official website. I don't want to install android studio. After unzipping the package, i got a folder called tools. I put into a directory as 
`/home/ujjwal/Android/tools`.
I opened the directory with the terminal and tried the command `./android` i got the following error :

```
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

I even tried using the command `android` but it shows `no command found`.
echo $ANDROID_HOME returns :

```
/home/ujjwal/Android/tools
```

echo $PATH returns:

```
/home/ujjwal/bin:/home/ujjwal/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ujjwal/Android/tools/tools
```

Also while i was working on another machine a while back, I remember that a small window used to open in which i could choose which tools and apk to install. Basically, I am trying to achieve that.

Comment: as the output says `android` command is deprecated..what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying open the sdk manager

Comment: What the output says, except that the android command is deprecated, is that you are missing arguments. Try one of the "Supported commands" that it lists.

Comment: For all of them it returns : `No command 'android' found, did you mean:
 Command 'androdd' from package 'androguard' (universe)
android: command not found
`

Answer (score 1):

`android` command is deprecated as shown by the output.

Use

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager <option>

 Usage:   
 sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file
 <file>] [<packages>...]   
 sdkmanager --update [<common args>]  
 sdkmanager --list [<common args>]   
 sdkmanager --licenses [<common
 args>]
```

You can also set the path to `sdkmanager` command in your `$PATH` variable for direct use.

Comment: if i want to open the sdk manager what do i put in the <option> space? If i leave it blank, it shows `no file or directory`

Comment: check the usage.. use one of the supported arguments in place of options

Comment: try `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager` also

Comment: `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager` works but  if i enter `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --list[]` its asking for arguments inside the list[] brackets. Also while i was working on another machine a while back, I remember that a small window used to open in which i could choose which tools and apk to install. Basically, I am trying to achieve that

Comment: sorry formatting problem :p .. just do `$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --list`

Comment: Yeah i got the list, but is there a way i can install them without typing it all out as arguments. Also what about that window i mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: For that you need to run the android studio itself. These are command line tools.Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/43603039/4826457 as well